# Fortran OpenMP - process things in parallel as they are released

Tags: fortran, queue, openmp, fifo

I'm trying to speed up an existing Fortran program with OpenMP.

A fixed number of things are to be processed in parallel, some of which may be processed immediately, while others can only be processed after they are released later.  In the end, each thing gets released exactly once.  Not compilable pseudocode...

```
! Each thing, 1..numthings, is released exactly once --- some now, some later
   numleft = numthings
   do i = 1, numthings
      if ( ok_to_release(i) ) then
         release(i)
      end if
   end do
!$OMP PARALLEL DO SCHEDULE(DYNAMIC,1) DEFAULT(SHARED) PRIVATE(i)
   do while( .TRUE. )
      wait until there is at least one released, unprocessed thing
      i = the first released, unprocessed thing  ! no other thread gets i
      numleft = numleft - 1
      process(i)                                 ! may release zero or more other things
      if ( numleft < numthreads ) exit           ! probably incorrect exit condition
   end do
!$OMP END PARALLEL DO
```

Am I on the right track please?  Can a multi-server fifo queue like this be easily implemented with OpenMP?

Thanks, Peter McGavin.

Comment: *Am I on the right track please?* Investigate OpenMP *tasks*.

Comment: I would argue that this is all that is needed for an answer ...

Comment: Many thanks.  I will read up about OpenMP tasks.  Traversing a tree in parallel is pretty much what the code needs to do...

Comment: The OpenMP examples document provided with the standard shows tree traversal using tasks in Fortran. https://www.openmp.org/wp-content/uploads/openmp-examples-5.0.0.pdf (pdf page 77 et seq.)